# how to set a background image of a button to nothing

Tags: swift, image, button, null

In my swift code I want to have a state fro the button that displays no image. It should be completely blank. I tried to do that with my swift code below but I am getting a error message no matches in call to initializer.

```
 BTN.setImage(UIImage(nil), for: .selected)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the whole image to be nil rather than passing nil to the UIImage initializer. Try this:

```
BTN.setImage(nil, for: .selected)
```